# composer cannot allocate memory inside container docker

Tags: symfony, docker, composer-php, docker-compose

I currently use *docker* to run my *Symfony3*. But I get this error when I try to run **`composer update`** inside my container (after doing command `docker exec -it <name of the bash container>`)

```
[ErrorException]
Proc_open (): fork failed - Can not allocate memory
```

The composer documentation asks to configure the swap of the machine but I get this error by following the steps of the documentation

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024 (OK)                     
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1 (OK)
```

> **`/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1 (KO)`** -->
>   **Swapon: /var/swap.1: swapon failed: Operation not permitted**

(Even though I'm in root mode)

Comment: Try to use `SYS_ADMIN` with `cap_add`  (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#capadd-capdrop)

Comment: Thx for your answer. I finally resolv this problem, check my post below ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem.

You can start by adding space on your virtual machine (default). In my case I switched from 1GB to 2GB.

Then you can, if you wish, launch your container with the option --memory-swap = -1 or a space you have chosen
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#memory-swap-details

It's OK for me now ;) .

Comment: Thank you, youre the best, elegant solution, also logical, but who would say, docker toolbox virtualbox default dispones only with 1 GB of memory, nowadays it is somehow not sufficient